# Start java with Java EE or Spring

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

I already know the syntax of Java, my next educational goal is to learn a framework (or library), some friends advice me to go for Spring some other advice me to go for Java EE 6.

I wonder which is better to start learning and practicing with. Would you please help me to choose a book or manual to enter the practical world of Java?

Comment: What is your end goal?  Is it only to write web applications?

Comment: I think learning Spring will introduce you to some concepts (i.e., Dependency Injection) that will help you improve your designs and coding.  It's non-trivial to configure, however.  You can use it with stand-alone applications or web apps.

Comment: Check out [AppFuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home) for a great way to get a nice introduction to various frameworks. At the very least, have a look at some of the [Demos and Videos](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Demos+and+Videos) showing how a basic project is set up. It allows you to explore the code and get a feel for how the chosen framework operates.

Comment: Asking for a recommendation on Spring vs JEE, and asking for a book or manual is considered Not Constructive since it's highly subjective. Check the FAQ.

Comment: Well it's just the matter of learning, I have no goal. I was PHP programmer for four years and recently I decided to test some java too. So I have no goal in mind but I am sure for 99 percent I am going to use java as a server side language on web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to start learning basic Java EE concepts (as you said you are php developer and you just started to learn java syntax). Because to understand Java EE frameworks you need to know what is [***Servlet***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servlet) and [***JSP***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) and other basic concepts like filters or servlet container (like [***tomcat***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat)). After you developed some simple Java EE application with Servlet and JSP you would be ready to learn more advanced concepts and frameworks (like Spring). 
My advice is start to read [***Head First Servlet & JSP***](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516681) or any online resources that learns you these concepts.

Good luck.